# In postgres db how do we get notifications or triggeres when the future column data (with timestamp) meets current time

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pg-notify

From UI user will give us some specific time (with timezone )for updating the exe version on the devices
which we are storing in postgresql db as demandedInstallationTime.

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id | DeviceName | demanded Installation Time | Other data  |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead of polling in Java for every minute to check the table if there is any entry with **'demandedInstallationTime'** and then invoke installation, I am thinking from postgresql tools.
like pg_notify() but that works when there is Insert/Update/Delete of row of the table.

Cron jobs will also need to be scheduled to run either minutely or hourly, etc. continuously 24/7 which is not feasible in our case.

I wanted some thread to notify/trigger some script automatically when **'demandedInstallationTime' column equals 'current time'**. How can we achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with database means. You need some kind of scheduled job.

Comment: for PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS? using some CloudWatch Events  and lambda functions? I am new to AWS so not sure , just started analyzing on that part. Please let me know your views too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know Amazon's services.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a trigger written in say [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) (other languages also available) which execute an external script of some kind. You'd need to carefully consider any possible performance/security implications of doing this kind of thing, of course.

Alternatively you could write a script which runs as a daemon and checks for updates (e.g. in a queue table written by a trigger on the table you're interested in) or which listens for notifications. If you're feeling really adventurous you could write a [custom background worker](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html), but that would probably be unnecessarily complex for the desired purpose.